# Kafka consume message in reverse order

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use Kafka 0.10, I have a Topic `logs` where my IoT devices post their logs into , The key of my messages are the `device-id` , so all the logs of the same device are in the same partition.

I have an api  `/devices/{id}/tail-logs` that needs to display the N last logs of one device at the moment the call was made.

Currently I have it implemented in a very unefficient way (but working), as I start from the beginning (i.e oldest logs) of the partition containing the device's log until I reach current timestamp.

A more efficient way would be if I could get the current latest offset and then consume the messages backward (I would need to filter out some message to keep only those of the device i'm looking for)

Is it possible to do it with kafka ? If not how one can solve this problematic ? (a more heavy solution I would see would be to have a kafka-connect linked to an elastic search and then to query the elasticsearch but to have 2 more components for this seems a bit overkill...)

Comment: I am not 100% sure, if I understand your application completely. You "display the N last logs" that basically means the N last messages from topic or partitions? How many partitions does you topic "logs" have and how do you define "last N messages" if there are multiple partitions? How does this relate to timestamp, as you say you read "from the beginning until [you] reach current timestamp"? It is not so easy to read backwards, but there is `.seek()` and `.endOffsets()` and `.offsetForTimestamp()` you can exploit for sure - to give a full answer, I would need to understand the scenario better

Comment: indeed my problem was not clear,  I've edited , I read the last N message from 1 partition

Comment: But a partition might have logs for multiple `device-id`s -- so reading the last N messages seems not to be sufficient. If might be helpful, to make your API stateful using Kafka Streams and Interactive Queries: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries What Kafka version do you use? 0.10.0, 0.10.1, or 0.10.2 ?

Comment: Yes you're right, actually that i was trying to say by `I would need to filter out some message to keep only those of the device i'm looking for` ,  I'm using 0.10.2 and still at the "proof of concept" phase, so if what i'm needing is in a beta version, i can wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are on 0.10.2, I would recommend to write a Kafka Streams application. The application will be stateful and the state will hold the last N records/logs per `device-id` -- if new data is written to the input topic, the Kafka Streams application will just update it's state (without the need to re-read the whole topic).

Furthermore, the application also serves you request ("api  `/devices/{id}/tail-logs`" using [Interactive Queries](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries) feature.

Thus, I would not build a stateless application that has to recompute the answer for each request, but build a stateful application that eagerly compute the result (and update the result automatically all the time) for all possible requests (ie, for all `device-id`s) and just returns the already computed result when a request comes in.

Comment: thanks, looking to the link to  interactive query, in your comments (which i think can be put in this answer too) it fits this need like a glove